# Java is asking me to create a method I have already created

Tags: java, methods

i am trying to call a method to generate a random number, but Java won't let me. It is telling me to create a method even though i already have. Here is my code.

```
package hw3;

import java.util.Random;

//Zephram Foster, Homework 3, 10-12

public class randomLottery {

    int num[];
    int ball;
    int high;


    public static int generateRandomInt(int upperRange){

        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(upperRange);
    }

}


package hw3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class randomMain {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the high number: ");
        //int high = sc.nextInt();
        //System.out.println(high);

        randomLottery rand = new randomLottery();
        rand.high = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(rand.high);

        rand.num[1] = generateRandomInt(rand.high);
    }

}
```

the problem is in the main class, the last line. Please help my dudes

Comment: `randomLottery.generateRandomInt(rand.high);`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You mean `randomLottery.generateRandomInt(rand.high);`.

Comment: @shmosel Didn't notice the `static`, but still: either should work.

Comment: yes, two different files

Answer (score 3):

The `generateRandomInt()` method is in another class.  Given that this method also happens to be static, you may refer to it as:

```
rand.num = new int[2];
rand.num[1] = randomLottery.generateRandomInt(rand.high);
```

Note that Java naming conventions say that class names should begin with a capital letter, so call the other class `RandomLottery`.

I don't know what the rest of your not yet written code would look like.  Java arrays begin an index zero, so the following assignment might make more sense:

```
rand.num[0] = randomLottery.generateRandomInt(rand.high);
```

Comment: or import static?

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the red underline, but it still wont run. Now when i run it with that change it tells me:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hw3.randomMain.main(randomMain.java:16)

Comment: You need to intialize the `int[]` array.

Comment: I wonder why `num` etc variables are in the `randomLottery` class.

Comment: Also Arrays in Java start at index `0`

Comment: @ScaryWombat If you see a can with a worm crawling out of it, and then you open it, what do you get?  You get a can of worms.

Comment: yes, I'll fix and have it start at 0. should the variable be somewhere else? I am new to java.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, Tim the comments were not aimed at you.  You still got my upvote